# View is not found when migrating from AspNet.Core 2.2 to 3.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, migration, asp.net-core-3.0

I have an Asp.Net Core 2.2 MVC application. I am trying to migrate to 3.0, using this documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio.

So in Startup.cs I replaced

```
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

with

```
        app.UseRouting();
        ...
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "Default", pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
```

I am getting

> InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' was not found. The following locations were searched:
>
> /Views/Home/Index.cshtml
>
> /Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
>
> /Pages/Shared/Index.cshtml

What am I missing?

ADDED: Here is my project file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
  <UserSecretsId>HIDDEN</UserSecretsId>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <None Remove="ScaffoldingReadme.txt" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="bootstrap-select" Version="1.13.12" />
  <PackageReference Include="CsvHelper" Version="12.1.2" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation" Version="3.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language" Version="3.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI" Version="3.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common" Version="4.1.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions" Version="3.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Analyzers" Version="3.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="3.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design" Version="1.1.6" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.0.0">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
  <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions" Version="3.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory" Version="3.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="3.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions" Version="3.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder" Version="3.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions" Version="3.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="3.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets" Version="3.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="3.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" Version="3.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions" Version="3.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical" Version="3.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing" Version="3.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="3.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" Version="3.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options" Version="3.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives" Version="3.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor" Version="2.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.2.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Sendgrid" Version="9.11.0" />
<PackageReference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" Version="4.5.0" />
<PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.8.3" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
<DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
<Content Update="Views\Allocation\Index.cshtml">
  <Pack>$(IncludeRazorContentInPack)</Pack>
</Content>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <None Update="appsettings.json">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </None>
</ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Follow your steps to migrate project from 2.2 to 3.0 version. It works fine in my side.

Then I rename the `Index.cshtml` -> `Index1.cshtml`, then I can reproduce the issue. So please check the Index.cshtml in your project, you also can click show all file button to check all the content.

[image]

Just make sure `Index.cshtml` file is not excluded from the project.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am not sure I understand though. I have Index.cshtml right there, in the Home folder, which is in the Views folder. And it is part of the project. Build Action is Content, and Copy to Output Directory: Do not copy.

Comment: Also, when I debug, I can see that execution hits a breakpoint inside HomeController.Index().

Comment: @DavidShochet Can you show your Index method ？

Comment: @Json 

public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

Comment: @DavidShochet Could you share your screenshoot about your project for us,  this issue seems very easy, like missing some settings. So we need to double check it.

Comment: I added the project file content to my question.

Comment: @DavidShochet It should be Views/Home/index.cshtml， not Views/Allocation/index.cshtml.

Comment: @DavidShochet You can move or paste the index.cshtml file under the Home folder， it will solve the issue

Comment: There is Index.cshtml under Home, and there is another Index.cshtml under Allocation. I added a screenshot to my question.

Comment: @DavidShochet does your project can be running normally in local?

Comment: I do run it in IIS Express from Visual Studio.

Comment: @DavidShochet thanks for your patience, and could you tell me when you faced the issue,I mean where you host the project? Azure web app? or IIS ?

Comment: IIS, on Azure VM. But again, right now I just run it in Visual Studio.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244534/discussion-between-jason-and-david-shochet).